# Create language plugin for eclipse rcp

Tags: eclipse, translation, rcp

It is possible to download language-plugins for eclipse. How would I create such a language plugin for my own eclipse rcp software?

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to create language fragments for your own bundles. [This article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Internationalization/how2I18n.html) describes how to do that - it's quite old, but its core information is still valid.

Comment: The plugin fragments got me set. Thank you!